# Can't understand why is the code before the thread.sleep(2000) getting delayed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using android studio,
Where I need to make a function that will make a button click effect
when clicked by changing its image resource for a few seconds
but when I am trying to do so the initial change gets delayed due to the thread.sleep(2000) which is after changing the image resource change code.

How is the possible ?

And am I using the efficient way to make a button click effect?

```
  void Click_effect(View view){


        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.after_click);
      
        try
        {

            // Delay for 2 seonds
            Thread.sleep(2000);

         // will use this to make the image like before
          //  view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.before_click);

        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Presumably this is an event-driven system and painting the change needs to happen in the same thread after Click_effect returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple `Handler` should provide the behaviour you require.

For example :

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        
        private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        
        void clickEffect(View view){
            view.setClickable(false); // optional disable clicks
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.after_click);
            handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                view.setClickable(true); // optional enable clicks
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.before_click);
            }, 2_000);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
}
```

or without restricting multiple clicks and a manual debounce to before state :

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    void clickEffect(View view){
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.after_click);
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.before_click);
        }, 2_000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```